# Change ID attribute dynamically in for-loop

Tags: javascript

The title could be misleading but i will try to explain.

I have an Ajax function that gets the value of some XML nodes. Now I want to change the ID of every created element with value of the xml-nodes.

I have something like this. 
XML file

```
<notes>
    <note>
        <text>Hello Dog</text>
        <id>1</id>
    </note>
    <note>
        <text>Hello Cat</text>
        <id>1</id>
    </note>
</notes>
```

Now for call every text node I use a loop

```
stickers = myXML.getElementsByTagName("note");
for( i = 0; i < stickers.length; i++) {
    var idNod =  (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var textNod = (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    add_sticker(idNod);
    add_sticker(textNod);
}
```

// add_sticker() is the function that created the elements dynamically ...

So the output of this will become

```
Note1 = Hello Dog id 1,
Note2 = Hello Cat id 2
```

But I want somehow to use the idNod and use it as ID attribute 
so it would  look something like this

```
<div id=1>hello dog</div>
<div id=2>hello Cat</div>
```

In the loop I entered

```
stickers[i].setAttribute("id", idNod);
```

But that didn't do anything, not neither gave me an error.

Comment: Why using setAttribute when you could do `stickers[i].id=idNod;` ?

Comment: Can you show your `add_sticker` function?

Comment: Except in HTML5 element IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: @dystroy I tried that to, but that wont change the id either.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
The soluton was to add a new variable var id = idNod... problem solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does your `add_stickers` are called twice to create one element? You should design your function to take both values and create the element.

```
function add_sticker(idNod, textNod) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = idNod;
    div.innerHtml = textNod;

    //Other parts
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what add_stickers does, so I'm stabbing in a dark just a little bit.  I would create a function that passes both the idNod and textNod values and then output the desired div

```
function addValues(id, text) {
   var div = "<div id=\"" + id + "\">" + text + "</div>";

   //add code here to append the above div to whatever element you need it to go to.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
The solution was thoug much simpler... I just added 
var id = idNod;
And all the ids got changes to correct value. :) Thanks anyhow :)